# How many li there are inside ul with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-lists

How can I know how many `li` there are inside in the first `ul`?

I know I can use .length, but I want just the number of first-ul

```
<ul class="first-ul">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>
        <ul class="second-ul">
            <li>2.1</li>
            <li>2.2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5oykbysk/

Comment: So you're asking how to select direct children of an element?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `>` to get immediate children `li`:

```
alert(number = $('ul.first-ul > li').length);
```

### FIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/5oykbysk/1/

See [**JQUERY DOCS for details**](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/)

Answer (score 4):

```
[].filter.call(
    document.getElementsByClassName('first-ul')[0].children, 
    function (el) {
        return el.nodeName === 'LI';
    }
).length
```

Comment: You can use whatever you'd like

Comment: Well that was just a suggestion.

Comment: Why the filter? The only valid child of a `ul` is an `li`.

Comment: @cookiemonster Sanity check I suppose.  Invalid children are still counted.

Answer (score 3):

use jQuery [`child selector`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/). Try this:

```
$('ul.first-ul > li').length
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/5oykbysk/2/)**

Answer (score 2):

it's the best and easy way :

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName(".first-ul").childElementCount;
alert (x);
```

Visit https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_childelementcount.asp